# Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jira-plugin

I try to set up helloworld plugin for jira and get the exception:

> Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-dispatcher-plugin:4.0:run (default-cli) on project helloworld: Unable to execute mojo: UnsupportedOperationException.....

My Environements:
JIRA - sdk-installer-4.0
java 1.6_0.32
maven 3.0.5(copy conf folder from sdk-installer-4.0 and paste into maven 3.0.5)

I clean .m2 local repository
Turn off Windows Defende
Try to set up project use this commands

```
atlas-clean
atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse
atlas-compile
atlas-debug
```

But not result.
Have you any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: have a look at the maven settings. the atlassian sdk reconfigures those to connect to their own repositories and plugins. Usually there is a script that sets the environment variables correctly. It seems you are using different settings. try "mvn help:effective-settings" - the atlassian repositories should be in there. You need to use their scripts for the maven commands.

Comment: ~/.m2/repository default repository into maven settings.xml

Comment: now i use maven 2,1 and get this error, i think this is a same error

Comment: can you post the complete error you get? I think the excerpt is too short. Also it may be the Java version. The docs https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started contain screenshots using Java 6 but that may just be deprecated. I would use a newer Java version.

Comment: i have to create plugin for jira 4.4.4 beacuse of that i must be use java 1.6.32, sdk4 –  Beginner 50 mins ago                                                        can you post the complete error you get?  please see this link https://yadi.sk/i/zVyMUZbOh5c6H

Comment: there is an answer at atlassian that probably solves this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/277302/a-required-class-is-missing-lorg-apache-maven-plugin-buildpluginmanager

Comment: same problem after then i change artifactId for com.atlassian.maven.plugins    https://yadi.sk/i/j7z6hpmYh5egX

Comment: For maven version 2.1.0: I changed M2_REPO in my Environement, 
set M2_REPO(e.g this - C:\Users\MyUser\atlassian-plugin-sdk-4.0\repository), 
after that i edited my settings.xml file(C:\Users\MyUser\atlassian-plugin-sdk-4.0\apache-maven\conf\settings.xml ), 
in this file added <localRepository>${env.M2_REPO}/</localRepository>     
After atlassian installation,  default M2_REPO = C:\Users\HHOVHANN\.m2\repository, because of that need to change it new one(e.g this - C:\Users\MyUser\atlassian-plugin-sdk-4.0\repository).
Thanks a lot 
For maven version 3.0.5 my problem remained the same.